# How to show that $|x|^p \leq p^p (e^x + e^{-x})$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , $p>0$?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, inequality

> Show that $|x|^p \leq p^p (e^x + e^{-x})$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p > 0$.

---

[**Motivation**:]
This inequality shows up when I am trying to relate the moments of a random variable to the moment generating function.

Comment: Is there any other information about $p$?

Comment: no, it should be true for all positive p

Comment: This is a problem-statement imperative.  No real question is asked; it merely attempts to assign to us, what was assigned to you, hoping someone will do it for you.  No effort shown, no thoughts added, no description of what you don't understand, or where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this in stages. Firstly, we all agree that for $t \geq 0$
$$ e^{t} \geq 1+t > t. $$
(Convexity, or use the power series, or whatever.) Therefore, for $y>0$,
$$ y/p \leq e^{y/p}, $$
or
$$ y \leq p\sqrt[p]{e^y}. $$
Hence, since $t \mapsto t^p$ is increasing,
$$ y^p \leq p^p e^y $$
Thus for any $x$,
$$ \lvert x \rvert^p \leq p^p e^{\lvert x \rvert}, $$
and the result follows since $e^{\lvert x \rvert} < e^{x}+e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry between the cases $x>0$ and $x<0$, we may assume $x>0$ (the case $x=0$ is trivial). We will show that $$\left(\frac xp\right)^p<\left(\exp\frac xp\right)^p=\mathrm e^x<\mathrm e^x+\mathrm e^{-x}.$$The left-hand inequality holds because $t<1+t+\frac12t^2+\frac16t^3+\cdots=\exp t$ for all $t>0$ (actually for $t\leqslant0$ as well), while the function $t\mapsto t^p$ is increasing for $t>0$. The right-hand inequality holds because $\mathrm e^{-x}$ is positive for all $x$. Now multiplying through by $p^p$ gives the required result.